# I can't import Firebase in my JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to install firebase in my JavaScript project. But when I open the `.js` script I have problem with `import`. How I can fix it?

Code:
`import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';`

Error:

```
(node:3168) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\Mr_Restmah\OneDrive - Technical University of Moldova\Desktop\Programare Calculatoare\Bulls and Cows\firebase.js:1
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
```

package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.12.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "type": "module" in the package.json

Comment: I set it but it doesn't work

Comment: Install the latest version of Node.js. It has the latest and greatest features.

Comment: I have the latest version

Comment: Please copy your package.json file to the question so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Are you using Typescript?

Comment: No, I don't use